# Trying to access object in Api array and count length

Tags: javascript

Trying to access the mythic object and print the length of mythic's that exist in the account but unsure how to access it as its nested in the array. Api output is below Javascript. Just not sure exactly what I can use to get its length as I used json.mythic.length and that did not work. And Thank you very much to anyone who is able to help me with this problem.

```
function MyFunction(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value
      document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = username;
      
      

const data = {
    username, limit: 3000, offset: 0, rarities: [], markers: [], onSale: "", search: "" }
      
fetch("https://prod-eternal-backend.onrender.com/api/v1/moment/list" ,{
     
   
    method: "POST",
     
    
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
     
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }

})

 

.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})
 

.then(json => {

    

    console.log(json);
    document.getElementById("moments").innerHTML ="Total Moments = " +  json.moments.length;
    var mythics = json.mythic.length * 50;
    document.getElementById("gamer").innerHTML ="Gamer Score = " +  mythics;
    
})
}
```

```
{
    "moments": [
        {
            "id": 114375,
            "playId": 536,
            "setId": 16,
            "serialNumber": 4,
            "username": "pattonh84",
            "userId": 1230,
            "userAuthId": "AqXfuefDt5a5wfqAoIa45O1RKbd2",
            "influencer": "YuggieTV",
            "influencerId": "YuggieTV",
            "influencerAvatar": "https://eternal-zelos.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/influencers/YuggieTV_square.png",
            "playbackId": "QXMRHp9R4uFcSsCQkN7mBCDbSmFZdImdjeUHypEutRw",
            "rarity": "mythic",
            "createdAt": "2021-10-25T00:11:54.734962Z",
            "setName": "Flow State",
            "circulationCount": 30,
            "title": "How Strong Could It Be?",
            "imageURL": "https://eternal-zelos.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/FlowFest/Let+Me+See+How+Strong+It+Is.png",
            "packName": "Flow State",
            "clipDate": "2021-09-26T02:55:28Z",
            "tags": [
                "funny"
            ],
            "description": "Yuggie doing experiments in the name of science. Today's experiment is about how strong a watermelon could be.",
            "game": "IRL",
            "twitter": "yuggietv",
            "staked": false,
            "autographStatus": "false",
            "discordUtility": false,
            "markers": null
        },
        {
            "id": 108262,
            "playId": 565,
            "setId": 16,
            "serialNumber": 1,
            "username": "pattonh84",
            "userId": 1230,
            "userAuthId": "AqXfuefDt5a5wfqAoIa45O1RKbd2",
            "influencer": "Amouranth",
            "influencerId": "Amouranth",
            "influencerAvatar": "https://eternal-zelos.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/influencers/Amouranth.jpg",
            "playbackId": "101L8XUOTCKkJW3USj6rtiJm5k4iTAwTIMqcxfPsr8QA",
            "rarity": "mythic",
            "createdAt": "2021-10-22T17:07:38.357172Z",
            "setName": "Flow State",
            "circulationCount": 30,
            "title": "Mare Awareness",
            "imageURL": "https://eternal-zelos.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/FlowFest/amouranth+pretending+to+be+a+horse.png",
            "packName": "Flow State",
            "clipDate": "2021-09-26T04:21:46Z",
            "tags": [
                "funny"
            ],
            "description": "Now a popular gif, this clip showcases a horse performance complete with galloping and internal monalogue.",
            "game": "Just Chatting",
            "twitter": "Amouranth",
            "staked": false,
            "autographStatus": "pending",
            "autographRequestId": 2071,
            "discordUtility": false,
            "markers": null
        },
        {
            "id": 114393,
            "playId": 536,
            "setId": 16,
            "serialNumber": 22,
            "username": "pattonh84",
            "userId": 1230,
            "userAuthId": "AqXfuefDt5a5wfqAoIa45O1RKbd2",
            "influencer": "YuggieTV",
            "influencerId": "YuggieTV",
            "influencerAvatar": "https://eternal-zelos.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/influencers/YuggieTV_square.png",
            "playbackId": "QXMRHp9R4uFcSsCQkN7mBCDbSmFZdImdjeUHypEutRw",
            "rarity": "mythic",
            "createdAt": "2021-10-22T03:35:24.934307Z",
            "setName": "Flow State",
            "forSale": true,
            "circulationCount": 30,
            "price": 200,
            "title": "How Strong Could It Be?",
            "imageURL": "https://eternal-zelos.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/FlowFest/Let+Me+See+How+Strong+It+Is.png",
            "packName": "Flow State",
            "clipDate": "2021-09-26T02:55:28Z",
            "tags": [
                "funny"
            ],
            "description": "Yuggie doing experiments in the name of science. Today's experiment is about how strong a watermelon could be.",
            "game": "IRL",
            "twitter": "yuggietv",
            "staked": false,
            "autographStatus": "false",
            "discordUtility": false,
            "productId": 67358,
            "markers": null
        }
    ],
    "totalMoments": 3
}
```

Comment: Where does mythic come from? The API data doesn't have it

Comment: There's not a `mythic` property in the JSON you posted.

Comment: Could there be a `".../v1/mythic/list"` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a `mythic` property on your JSON object, but your data does not have such a property. I would recommend that you study more on JSON structure and accessing properties in javascript.

Basically, `json.mythics` checks for a property called `mythics` in the root level of your `json` object, the same way `json.moments` does. If your data was organized like:

```json
{
  "moments": [...],
  "mythics": [...]
}
```

then you would access it with `json.mythics`

---

But your json only has a `moments` array of objects, some of which have a `rarity` property set to `"mythic"`.

Assuming you want to filter out these elements from the array, a simple [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should suffice:

```js
const mythics = json.moments.filter(moment => moment.rarity === 'mythic');
mythics.length // gives the length of the 'mythics'
```